# Call to undefined method Log::setUserId()

Tags: php

I have a generic Logger class that looks like this:

```
class Logger {

  ...
  
  public function add($userId, $siteId, $logTypeId, $message) {
    $Log = LogMapper::create();
    $Log->setUserId($userId);
    $Log->setSiteId($siteId);
    $Log->setLogTypeId($logTypeId);
    $Log->setMessage($message);
    $Log->save();
    
    ...
  }
  
  ...

}
```

And the Log class:

```
class Log {
  
  public function setUserId($userId) {
    if ($this->userId !== $userId) {
      $this->userId = $userId;
    }
    
    return $this;
  }
  
  public function getUserId() {
    return $this->userId;
  }

  public function setSiteId($siteId) {
    if ($this->siteId !== $siteId) {
      $this->siteId = $siteId;
    }
    
    return $this;
  }
  
  public function getSiteId() {
    return $this->siteId;
  }

  ...

}
```

As well as the LogMapper class:

```
class LogMapper extends DataMapper {

  ...

  public static function create($row = false) {
    return new Log($row);
  }

  public static function getById($id) {
    ...
  }

}
```

As you can see, I have two other classes, LogMapper and Log, which Logger uses to write records to a database.

I also have a mechanism that emails me when a fatal error occurs. I received the following in about a dozen emails:

> Call to undefined method Log::setUserId()

My application uses autoloading, and I first thought that may be the problem, but clearly the Logger class is being loaded, and so autoloading has not broken. The path for the Log class is correct in the autoloader...and clearly the Log class has been loaded--otherwise a "Class 'Log' not found" error would have been thrown.

Any ideas what may be causing this error? I do use eAccelerator on the release.

Comment: Were the dozen emails all of them? does the problem still appear if you don't use autoload but test the classes in some other way? And, most obviously, does the method setUserId() exist in class Log?

Comment: Maybe the mapper does not map the methods correctly, this is why the Log class can not recognize any setUserId() method.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem locally actually, so I can't tell whether not using the autoloader helps.

Comment: Looking at the code (I updated with the Log class definition), it looks like it's called correctly. In fact, this same code works in other places in the code base, but in one place, it fails for some reason.

Comment: Does the LogMapper delegate to the log class to set the userID? It'd help to see the LogMapper class

Comment: Posted the LogMapper class. The Log class does not delegate setting the user id in either the Log object or the database. The LogMapper just creates and populates new instances of Log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long shot, but do you have PEAR's Log class installed?  This is something I ran across a while back.  I tried to make a 'Log' class but it was colliding with PEAR's.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your post. That was the problem: PayPal has a 'Log' class. If I could kiss you, well, I still wouldn't, but I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post your `Log` class here, the best guess anyone can probably make is that you forgot to write a `setUserId()` method in that class.

I can also take a guess that eAccelerator might have your class cached.  It's possible you need to restart your web server for changes to take effect, or utilize some other method of clearing the cache.

Comment: Oops...posted that. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Hmm... you've got `setSiteId()` there, but not `setUserId()`.

Comment: From your comments above, I'm going with an eAccelerator issue.  Try restarting your web server.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not totally convinced it's an eAccelerator cache issue, as I've never, ever experienced an issue that was resolved by restarting the web server or just Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reflection can tell you a bit more about the actual `class Log` used by your code.

```
public function add($userId, $siteId, $logTypeId, $message) {
  $Log = LogMapper::create();
  if ( !method_exists($Log, 'setUserId') ) {
    $ro = new ReflectionObject($Log);
    echo 'class defined in ', $ro->getFilename(), ' @ ', $ro->getStartLine(), "\n";
    foreach($ro->getMethods() as $rm) {
      echo '  method ', $rm->name, " \n";
    }
    die('----');
  }
  $Log->setUserId($userId);
  $Log->setSiteId($siteId);
  $Log->setLogTypeId($logTypeId);
  $Log->setMessage($message);
  $Log->save();
}
```

Comment: I would totally do that, except I can't test using the release :(

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, we can't see the Log class nor the LogMapper.
You sure the Log class has setUserId() method?
Also why do you name the variable with uppercase? $Log?

Comment: Oops...posted that. That was the first thing I checked. By my company's naming convention, we name object instances in title case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess:

Use:

```
public function __set($name,$value)
{
$this->{preg_replace('^set','',$name)} = $value; 
}
```

This would be a real mapping, I guess.

*//Call me stupid, but I still can not find the setUserId() method?
//Did you leave it out, while copy&pasting the code? **OUTDATED***

Comment: Yeah...I am distracted today...I re-updated the post. Sorry about that. Believe me, I'd love to use magic methods, but I can't due to non-technical reasons.

Comment: Why? Couldn't you use them? A wrapper/mapper won't be a "real" mapper if he could not use magic methods^^

Comment: True. My co-worker was just unconvinced for some reason to use them.

Comment: "Some" strange "reasons" I assume. =) Yes, let him be unconvinced, but setter and getter methods are "THE" important and new things in PHP5+. They improve and expand the OOP in PHP.

Comment: daemonfire300: getters and setters break encapsulation (leak implementation details), and go contrary to the basic principle of OOP: classes are supposed to be data members + behavior that uses those data members.  as soon as you have `interface Order { public /* Dollar */ function getTotal(); }`, you have code which uses a data member from a different class.  maybe `Order` should have `public /* bool */ function display(Display $d);` instead...?

Comment: @js, I do not agree with you at every point: Because a web application is most of the time a variable "object" with can have various attributes. Like a prism, reflecting different types of light. To represent this "object" we mostly need to use setter and getter. That is what I wanted to say with "improve" and "expand". Actually a wrapper doesn't wrap a object it wraps a request, which I think does not break the main rules of OOP. Tell me if I am wrong =)

Comment: One adversity to using __set and __get would be that code documentation would not reflect the methods available to the data models.

Answer (score -1):

try this

if ($this->userId !== $userIdd)

make the var names diffrent, i had such a weird problem one day.

Comment: Your "answer" has absolutely nothing to do with the problem. The problem involves an undefined method, but your answer is trying to address some nonexistent problem with variable names.